# SSH on computer JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ssh

The other day I made a Cydia repository on my site. I wanted to have a button on my site that would add it without user input. So, the idea was to do some sshing through JavaScript.

Could anyone point me to a project that has to do with SSH? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This is one I'm familiar with](http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/sample_remote_terminal.html), though there are [others out there](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AjaxTerm), I'm surprised you didn't seem to try [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+term&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS461US461&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS461US461&sclient=psy-ab&q=ajax+terminal&oq=ajax+terminal&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i30l3.3068.3387.0.3577.4.3.0.1.1.0.76.222.3.3.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.cqaXLgcvjRM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=4c4e4dd9cacdc02d&biw=1600&bih=832).